# UWP URI for making a call

Tags: mobile, uwp

I'm working on a UWP app that uses a RichTextBlock to display some text that the user can enter, I want it to Identify phone numbers so that I can tap the number and then the application should take me to the call app or people app and give me the option to call this number. I search for a solution for that and what I found so far is in this link:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-default-app

I couldn't find the URI that I can use to make it work, the best thing that I've achieved so far is by using a hyperlink that contains the following:

```
 if(isPhoneNumber)
       hyper = @"ms-people:savetocontact?PhoneNumber="+hyper+"&Email=&ContactName=";
```

but now when I tap the number the people app is launched on the contacts list screen.

Any advice would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `tel:<phone-number>` uri scheme. You will get the below page where you can send text message, call or save this number. Eg.:

```
await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("tel:+36301234567"));
```

[image: tel: uri scheme result]

Comment: Thank you very much it worked, I just replaced my hyper link to "tel:"+hyper and the hyperlink is working now, how come this URI not mentioned on MSDN URI page? anyway thank you for your help.