# Call a chosen TEL number automatically in my c# application

Tags: c#, triggers, tel

I have a CRM Desktop application (Windows Forms / c#) and i'm using a specicfic application to make calls (AirCall Application in my situation).

How can i make a button which can trigger the call  : so when i choose a number it will be called automatically with the default PC application (AirCall in my situation)?

Any help?and thanks

Comment: Create a MyButton that inherits the standard Button (public class MyButton : Button).  Then add a property to MyButton for the TEL number.  Then when you get into the click method you will have the phone number property set.

Answer (score 2):

There are plenty of resources on [creating a basic UI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-wpf?view=vs-2019). The difficult part will be to launch the telephone app.

The overall approach is to create an uri for telephone number. There are some different protocols used, like "sip:", "tel:" and "callto:" and probably others. You will need to look upp the documentation for your specific software to see what protocols they handle. Once you have an uri you can ask windows to launch the registered application for that protocol.

By asking the shell:

```
var url = "tel:+36301234567";
var psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
psi.UseShellExecute = true;
psi.FileName = url; 
Process.Start(psi);
```

Or by using UWP:

```
var success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri(@"tel:+36301234567"));
```

See also:

- [launch default application for URI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-default-app#call-app-uri-scheme)
- [UWP app for making a call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39017583/uwp-uri-for-making-a-call)
- [Launching an application URI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21977144/launching-an-application-with-an-uri-from-winform)

Answer (score -1):

You could also use Aircall Public API with the dedicated endpoints:

- [Start an outbound call](https://developer.aircall.io/api-references/#start-an-outbound-call)
- [Dial a phone number in the app](https://developer.aircall.io/api-references/#dial-a-phone-number-in-the-phone)