# Create clickable phone number in Visual Studio Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

First post here on SO and new to Visual Studio. I'm working on a basic application and I want it to have a clickable phone number, so when it's clicked, the number automatically dials out in Zoom.

I used the form creator to add a `LinkLabel` but I am having trouble figuring out how to make it clickable where the number dials out.

I haven't had much luck finding answers online but I may be using the wrong search criteria. I was hoping someone could provide an online resource that helps with this sort of thing or guide me in the right direction.

I tried something similar to the below but with a phone number and haven't figured it out

```
System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "mailto:email@email.com";
proc.Start();
```

**Update 12/26**

I appreciate some of the comments. The below code starts the Zoom process. Now I just need to figure out how to dial a specific phone number when the application is launched. I'll keep playing around with the code, but it would be super helpful if anyone else has ideas.

Form.cs

```
   private void linkLabel2_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
        {
            string zoomDirectory = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"C:\Program Files\ZoomVDI\bin");
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = $@"{zoomDirectory}\Zoom.exe",
       
            };
            Process.Start(startInfo);
        }
```

Form1.Designer.cs

```
// PhoneNumber
            // 
            this.PhoneNumber.AutoSize = true;
            this.PhoneNumber.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 15F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.PhoneNumber.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(143, 159);
            this.PhoneNumber.Name = "PhoneNumber";
            this.PhoneNumber.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(136, 25);
            this.PhoneNumber.TabIndex = 3;
            this.PhoneNumber.TabStop = true;
            this.PhoneNumber.Text = "000-000-0000";
            this.PhoneNumber.LinkClicked += new System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabelLinkClickedEventHandler(this.linkLabel2_LinkClicked);
```

Comment: Perhaps this link may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64803548/how-to-start-zoom-meeting-automatically-from-c-sharp-console-application

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to start Zoom meeting automatically from C# Console Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64803548/how-to-start-zoom-meeting-automatically-from-c-sharp-console-application)

Comment: Thanks for some of the comments. I made additional changes which launch the Zoom app. Almost success! Now I just need to figure out how to dial a specific phone number once the app is launched.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to open the dial app you should use `tel:xxxxxxxxxxx`, like [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61922377/16690868).